# Simple read into string from file Swift OSX?

Tags: swift, macos

In the playground (Xcode 7, Swift 2.1) for OSX, this creates nothing but an empty string:

```
let fileString = "/Users/me/file.txt"
var text = try NSString( contentsOfFile: fileString, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding )
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
$ cat /Users/me/file.txt
```

in the Terminal confirms that the file contains ASCII content.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code reads a file but you are asking about create a file - which are you after?

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I want to create a string named text from a file named file.txt in directory /Users/me in OSX. Cat /Users/me/file.txt produces content. Sorry about the typo in my first line :) -- fixed that!

Comment: Just test your code in a project, playground it is sandboxed.

Comment: @LeoDabus it's not a duplicate because the question is about accessing a file in a Playground.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33404160/2303865 would you like to reopen it and post this one?

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/a/29289914/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus I didn't want to be nitpicking but it might be confusing for ingenuous people to be redirected to a slightly different topic ;-)

Comment: @vadian the title doesn't even mention playground

Comment: Right, this is confusing, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically a Playground is sandboxed and has no access to the file system.

To play with files you have to add them to the Resources folder of the Playground and access them with

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("file", ofType: "txt")
```

It's always recommended to wrap a `try` statement in a `do - catch` block and catch the error.

**Update:**

For example

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource( "file", withExtension: "txt")!
do { 
  let text = try NSString( contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) 
} catch let errOpening as NSError { 
  print("Error!", errOpening) 
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer using your sample code.